# Python HTTPBaseServer: route requests to multiple request handlers

Tags: python, http, server

I have couple of standalone HTTP servers (based on `BaseHTTPServer`) which I want to combine into one server (based on `BaseHTTPServer` as well)

I want to fire up the request handler class of each of my already implemented servers based on the incoming request URL.

For example: for a reqeust to `/api1` in my new server use `Api1RequestHandler` and so on..

Do you have an idea how should i do this? Can i use the instance of the new server's request handler in order to call other handlers?

This is an example of the idea:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class Api1Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.headers)


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        my_handler2 = Api1Handler(self.request, self.client_address, self.server)
        my_handler2.do_GET()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), MyHandler)

    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    server.server_close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out I just have to inherit the already implemented handlers classes in my main handler class.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class Api1Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("win")
        print(self.headers)


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler, Api1Handler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        Api1Handler.do_GET(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), MyHandler)

    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    server.server_close()
```